# Python: how to maintain independence from instance?

Tags: python, refactoring, instance

I'm refactoring a program of mine. Basically I move all classes into a module.

Now I'm facing the problem that some of the module code is dependent on instances of a class I instantiated in my main program. Of course I could pass the instance to the method directly. Or `pickle` the instance. Or define the attribute as `global`. Which is the best way to go?

Comment: Without seeing code, this is almost impossible to answer; too broad, too vague, I am afraid. *Generally* speaking, if code depends on specific state, then it is best to pass in that state as an argument.

Comment: I was afraid somebody would say that. But putting all my code here isn't really an option either. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sounds like you should read up on dependency injection.

Comment: Fancy title. Will do. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility might be to pass the instance to the class upon instantiation:

```
class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, inst):
        self.inst = inst
    def method(self):
        # use self.inst

inst = Foo()
bar = Bar(inst)
```

Comment: This not a bad idea in my case. Thanks.